# Printing lowercase, uppercase, and number of numbers

Tags: c, uppercase, lowercase

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() { 
   char text[1000];
   int ch;
   int index = 0;

   while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
      text[index] = ch;
      index++;
   }
   text[index] = '\0';

   int i =0;
   int num_Count=0; 
   int lower_Count=0; 
   int upper_Count =0;

   while(i < index) {
    if((text[i]>='0') && (text[i]<='9')){
        num_Count ++;
        i++;
    }
    else if((text[i]>='A') && (text[i]<='Z')){
        upper_Count++;
        i++;
    }
    else if((text[i]>='a') && (text[i] <='z')){
        lower_Count++;
        i++;
    }
    else
        i++;
}
printf("%d %d %d", num_Count, lower_Count, upper_Count);
return 0;
}
```

It is a program that outputs the number of lower case, upper case, and number when the sentence is inputted.
For example,

```
Hi
Name
100
```

Would output `3 4 2`

I keep seeing a runtime error.
The (while) part seems to be wrong.. I do not know what's wrong.

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: That is 'runtime error'..

Comment: While it's good you don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), it would be even better if you used the standard [character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: As for your problem, now seems to be the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes as and when they happen.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code in my system and checked for the input: `Hi Name 100`. The output I got is `3 4 2` which is the expected output. I feel the only place where the code can run in an infinite loop is while reading the inputs. Try to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>d</kbd> for `EOF` or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>z</kbd> for windows.

Rest every thing is fine.

Answer (score 0):

EOF means End Of File. It is used when you read data from a file. I suggest put a character like newline ('\n').

Comment: Hitting Ctrl-D sets `EOF` as well.